# Change a link domain extension based on location

Tags: jquery

I have managed to get the country of the person visiting the website:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
  $("#hello").html(
        'Country: ' + data.address.country);
});
});
</script>

<p id="hello"></p>
```

Now what I'm struggling with is I have a basic link

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="global">Google</a>
```

and I want to change the url's extension based on location e.g.

```
if data.address.country = Australia change "www.google.com" to "www.google.com.au"
or if data.address.country = New Zealand change "www.google.com" to "www.google.co.nz"
or if data.address.country = Any thing else leave it as is "www.google.com"
```

I know that's no real code but hopefully its clear enough that you know where i'm coming from, possibly make the code generic so I can add other locations in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly, you'll need to map each of the countries to their respective URLs. You should use the exact value returned by your AJAX call as the key for the object.

```
var country = data.address.country;
var urls = {
  'Australia':'www.google.com.au',
  'New Zealand':'www.google.co.nz',
  ...
}
```

Now setup the default value for unmatched countries and if there is a matched country, replace the Google URL with the matched value.

```
var googleUrl = 'www.google.com';
if (urls[country]){
  googleUrl = urls[country];
}
```

Finaly, once you have selected the appropriate URL, you can change the `href` property using jQuery's `prop()` function.

```
$("#global").prop('href',googleUrl);
```

#### [A quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rjq5C/)

Comment: Thanks, your a legend, this was the best solution for my project.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a mapping:

```
var country_map = {
    'Australia': 'google.com.au',
    'New Zealand': 'google.co.nz'
    'Russia': 'google.ru'
};

var country = data.address.country;

if (country in country_map) {
    link.href = link.href.replace('google.com', country_map[country];
}
```

Google.com [redirects to a user's appropriate country](https://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=873), so I wouldn't actually touch the links to begin with.

Comment: Cheers, the real project isn't using Google but I look back now and think that was a silly demo url to use

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the href attribute dynamically

```
    $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
      $("#hello").html(
         'Country: ' + data.address.country);
      });
      $('#global').attr('href', map[data.address.country])
    });
```

Then somewhere in your code write a map that says

```
   var map = {
          'Australia': 'google.au',
          'India' : 'google.in'            

         }
```

Comment: Thanks, would never had thought of that way, will give it a shot a report soon, thanks again